# Can I set up materialised views for Postgres for a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, materialized-views

I have a table in a MySQL database that needs to be visible to an Postgre database.
How can I use a materialised view to do this?

Comment: You need to first make foreign tables pointing to your MySQL server and then create view out of them as normal. https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw

Comment: Ok. How can I use those views in Postgre

Comment: There is example on how to make such table in that website I have linked. You can also see example (but for postgres_fdw) in official documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/postgres-fdw.html
Syntax is the same, just different wrapper/extension.